# How to Update my Todo using Redux and React

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-router

I have a problem in my redux based todolist ,  where adding to the todo and deleting works ,  but i am not able to update the todo. i am using immunity helpers , it is updating the next item in the list and sometimes returns object is undefined!

This is my EditTodo

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { editTodo } from  '../../actions/editTodoActions'
class EditTodo extends Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            id:this.props.match.params.id,
            todo:this.props.todo[0].todo
        }
    }

    onInputChange = (e) => {
       const todo = e.target.value;
       this.setState({
         todo : todo
       })
    }

    editTodo = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        const todo = {
            id : this.state.id,
            todo: this.state.todo
        }
        this.props.editTodo(todo);
    }

    render() {
        const id = this.props.match.params.id
        console.log(this.props.todo)
        console.log(this.props.todo[0].todo)

        return (
            <div>
                <input className="todo" name="todo" onChange={this.onInputChange} value={this.state.todo} type="text" placeholder="enter todo" /> <br />
                <button onClick={this.editTodo}>Submit </button> 
            </div>
        )
    }
}

const MapStateToProps = (state,ownProps) =>({
    todo : state.todolist.filter((item) => item.id == ownProps.match.params.id)
})

const MapDispatchToProps = {
   editTodo : editTodo
}

export default connect(MapStateToProps,MapDispatchToProps)(EditTodo)
```

This is Edit Todo Action

```
import { EDIT_TODO } from './types'

export function editTodo(newTodo){
        return {
            type: EDIT_TODO,
            payload: {
                todo: newTodo
            }
        }
}
```

This is my Reducer :

```
import { ADD_TODO,EDIT_TODO, DELETE_TODO } from '../actions/types'
import update from 'immutability-helper'
const todolist = [
    { id :1, todo:"hello team"}
]

function todolistReducer(state=todolist,{ type, payload }){
        switch(type){
                case ADD_TODO:

                        let newTodo = { 
                                id: payload.todo.id, 
                                todo:payload.todo.todo
                        };
                         return state.concat([newTodo]);

                case EDIT_TODO:
                        console.log('edit todo called')
                        console.log(payload.todo.id)
                        return update(state, { 
                                  [payload.todo.id]: {
                                    todo: {$set: payload.todo.todo}
                                  }

                        });
                                // Now we know that foo is defined, we are good to go.
                case DELETE_TODO:
                        console.log('delete reducer called')
                 return  state.filter((item) => item.id != payload.id)

                default:
                return state

        }



}
export default todolistReducer
```

Answer (score 1):

The `update` method provided by `immutability-helper` accepts second parameter key as `index` of the object that need to be updated in the array.

In your case it's not working or updating the next object because the id's of the objects are defined starting from `1`. Ideally before updating you should find the index of the object the need to be updated and then use the same index to update the object in the array of `todo`s.

So I have created a utility to find out the index of the object need to be updated and then calling the `update` method

```js
export const todolist = [
  { id :1, todo:"hello team"},
  { id :2, todo:"hello team 2"}
]

const updateObj = (list, id, value) => {
    let index = list.findIndex(todo => todo.id === id)
    if(index === -1) return list;
    let updatedList = update(list, { 
      [index]: {
        todo: {$set: value}
      }
  })

   return updatedList;
}
  console.log(updateObj(todolist, 2, "updated value"))
  console.log(updateObj(todolist, 3, "updated value"))
```

In your example replace this below with `EDIT_TODO` case and use the above `updateObj` utility

```js
case EDIT_TODO:
    console.log('edit todo called')
    console.log(payload.todo.id)
    return updateObj(state, payload.todo.id, payload.todo.todo);
```

Here is a [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/throbbing-sky-8c5kt?file=/src/App.js) to the sample project I have created. Though it doesn't have reducers implementation but then updating the object works as per your requirement using `immutability-helper`s `update` method.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Can you tell me what is the error you are getting? Only scenario where you can get error is when you don't find eat index of the object that need to be updated.

Comment: Sorry, the return statement was missing. I have updated the code. Please verify with the latest code now.